# Best practices longtable

Tags: tables, longtable, best-practices

I have a long table with the explanation of 50 items (the MWE displays only 9). I believe this is hard to read. How do I make it easy to read?

```
\documentclass[10pt,cleardoublepage=empty,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{4.8cm} p{4.8cm}}
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, orci vivamus ac neque augue cras, pellentesque libero integer.}\\
\textsc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}&\textsc{Lorem ipsum}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{(continued)}\\
\endhead
\endlastfoot

aenean ipsum enim egestas dui amet, ut condimentum ipsum vel arcu ullamcorper, nec et quis dolor mi, nunc id laoreet velit elit sit orci. Pede vestibulum ac amet
&\textit{enean}\slash \textit{egestas}\\

pede vestibulum ac amet
&\textit{egestas}\slash \textit{condimentum}\\

aenean ipsum enim egestas dui amet, ut condimentum ipsum vel arcu ullamcorper, ante voluptatem, suspendisse sed euismod leo
&\textit{hasellus}\slash \textit{egestas}\\

pede vestibulum ac amet.
&\textit{egestas}\slash \textit{condimentum}\\

aenean ipsum enim egestas dui amet, ut condimentum ipsum vel arcu ullamcorper
&\textit{laoreet}\slash \textit{velit}\\

aenean ipsum enim egestas dui amet, ut condimentum ipsum vel arcu ullamcorper, ante voluptatem, suspendisse
&\textit{enean}\slash \textit{egestas}\\

mauris lectus vel nulla neque lectus vel nulla eget cras luctus enim pharetra, curabitur sed curabitur sed vitae, lectus vel nulla neque
&\textit{egestas}\slash \textit{condimentum}\\

mauris eget cras luctus enim pharetra, curabitur sed vitae, lectus vel nulla neque
&\textit{cras}\slash \textit{enim}\\

sapien in sed. Sit lectus sed nullam, condimentum elit quae, morbi lacus nullam dictum libero convallis 
&\textit{convallis}\slash \textit{Sit}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Output (extract):

[image: Table]

I also have this other table. Do you think it could look better than this?

```
\documentclass[10pt,cleardoublepage=empty,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{l l}
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh}\\
\textsc{Lorem Ipsum}&\textsc{Ament}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{(continued)}\\
\textsc{Semantic Category}&\textsc{Variable}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\endlastfoot
\multirow{3}{*}{consectetur eiusmod tempor}&\textit{dolor}/\textit{sit}\\ &\textit{ament}/\textit{sit}\\ &\textit{laboris}/\textit{explicabo}\\
\\
\multirow{3}{*}{consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod}&\textit{exercitationem}/\textit{voluptatem}\\ &\textit{incidunt}/\textit{laboris}\\
&\textit{aliquid}/\textit{explicabo}\\
\\
\multirow{2}{*}{consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do}& \textit{holiday}/\textit{exercitationem}\\
&\textit{sundown}/\textit{laboris}\\
\\
\multirow{2}{*}{consectetur adipisicing, sed do eiusmod}&\textit{laboris}/\textit{incidunt}\\
&\textit{exercitationem}/\textit{voluptatem}\\
\\
consectetur adipisicing elit, sed&\textit{aliquid}/\textit{incidunt}\\
\\
consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod&\textit{explicabo}/\textit{laboris}\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are all those packages necessary to run this code? If not, you should delete the ones that are not needed.

Comment: @Vivi: this is a MWE extracted from my whole dissertation. I am not so good at deciding which packages are necessary for my MWE. I did delete many from my standard preamble already.

Comment: MWE stands for "minimal working example" (emphasis on minimal). So it is not a MWE until you have removed all unnecessary packages. Have a look at [this good explanation](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/minexample.pdf). While it may appear I am being pedantic, there are many reasons why this should be done. If you are not sure which packages are important, coment out the lines that include a package one by one and try to compile the code. If it gives an error, uncomment that line and keep going. If anything, you will learn from that!

Answer (score 18):

**First suggestion:** increase space between rows, so that the paragraphs are not so crampled. This can be achieved by simply inserting in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
```

This is the result:

[image: With arraystretch]

**Second suggestion** Is it possible to swap columns? In this case, I would insert an `\hfill` in the shorter one in order to have it right-aligned with the longer one. I.e:

```
\begin{longtable}{>{\hfill}p{4.8cm}p{4.8cm}}  % <----- here 
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, orci vivamus ac neque augue cras, pellentesque libero integer.}\\
\textsc{Lorem ipsum} & \textsc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{(continued)}\\
\endhead
\endlastfoot

\textit{enean}\slash \textit{egestas}
& aenean ipsum enim egestas dui amet, ut condimentum ipsum vel arcu ullamcorper, nec et quis dolor mi, nunc id laoreet velit elit sit orci. Pede vestibulum ac amet
\\
\textit{egestas}\slash \textit{condimentum}
& pede vestibulum ac amet
\\
[etc.]
\end{longtable}
```

Resulting in:

[image: Swapped columns]

Finally, this table looks like a list of descriptions. If so, perhaps a `description` environment would be the best option.

Comment: +1 sorry I just saw your final comment after I'd produced the answer below using description.

Comment: How can I set the \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} only for this table and not for the rest of the text?

Comment: @Costi enclose all in braces: `{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}\begin{longtable} ... \end{longtable}}`

Answer (score 14):

On the general principle of avoiding all my packages, this looks more like a list than a table to me, something like:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,cleardoublepage=empty,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hbox to \textwidth{\hspace\labelsep
 \normalfont\bfseries\itshape #1}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, orci vivamus ac neque augue cras, pellentesque libero integer}
\subsection*{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}

\begin{description}
\item[enean\slash egestas]
aenean ipsum enim egestas dui amet, ut condimentum ipsum vel arcu ullamcorper, nec et quis dolor mi, nunc id laoreet velit elit sit orci. Pede vestibulum ac amet


\item[egestas\slash condimentum]
pede vestibulum ac amet

\item[hasellus\slash egestas]
aenean ipsum enim egestas dui amet, ut condimentum ipsum vel arcu ullamcorper, ante voluptatem, suspendisse sed euismod leo

\item[egestas\slash condimentum]
pede vestibulum ac amet.

\item[laoreet\slash velit]
aenean ipsum enim egestas dui amet, ut condimentum ipsum vel arcu ullamcorper

\item[enean\slash egestas]
aenean ipsum enim egestas dui amet, ut condimentum ipsum vel arcu ullamcorper, ante voluptatem, suspendisse

\item[egestas\slash condimentum]
mauris lectus vel nulla neque lectus vel nulla eget cras luctus enim pharetra, curabitur sed curabitur sed vitae, lectus vel nulla neque

\item[cras\slash enim]
mauris eget cras luctus enim pharetra, curabitur sed vitae, lectus vel nulla neque

\item[convallis\slash Sit]
sapien in sed. Sit lectus sed nullam, condimentum elit quae, morbi lacus nullam dictum libero convallis 
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The description list looks great. The only problem is that I must not use the bold face. How can I get rid of that? Also, is there a way to add a caption to a description list?

Comment: I have solved my own question about the bold face this way: \renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hbox to \textwidth{\hspace\labelsep
 \normalfont #1}}
The question about the caption is still open.

Comment: Also, last item alignement is crazy. It forces justification rather than aligning to the left.

Comment: how do you define "Caption" I used subsection heading in the example, but do you mean you want it to appear in the list of tables?

Comment: You are right: I did not notice your caption here. It is ok if the list does not go in the list of tables.

Comment: Not sure about your alignment comment, if you want the items raggedright use `\begin{description}\raggedright` or (better) define your own local environment that does that

Comment: Does not work with \raggedright. How do I define my local environment? I am working with the book class.

Comment: If \raggedright did not work you put it in the wrong place (incidentally you used justified not ragged paragraphs in your initial example) `\newenvironment{mydescription}{\description\raggedright}{\enddescription}`