# Longtable breaking lists in a cell

Tags: tables, lists, longtable

I'm trying to produce a CV. I'm using Latex and Python, so I can edit the underlying text document with my material easily and the finished cv will come up adjusted for the contents of each section.

I read that longtable cant paginate in the middle of a cell, so when I try and do an itemized list, it won't break up and I end up with a lot of whitespace at the bottom of one page and the whole list on the next.

How can I split the list? Is there another package I can use?

In the final program PdfLatex will be called by python on a calculated script. If I could find out what the overspill was I could force Python to produce two lists. Is there such a variable and how do I access it?

Thanks & MWE below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{4mm}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{longtable}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{0.9}}p{0.15\linewidth}|p{0.80\linewidth}|}
\hline\T
\textbf{Summary} & 
\makebox[2cm][l]{Blah:} Blah \\[2ex]
& \makebox[2cm][l]{Blah:} Blah\\
& \makebox[2cm][l]{} Blah \\
& \makebox[2cm][l]{} Blah\\[2ex]
& \makebox[2cm][l]{Blah:} blah\\
& \makebox[2cm][l]{} blah \\ \hline\T
\textbf{Blah} & 
\begin{itemize}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\Box$}
\vspace{-1em}
\itemsep0ex
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\end{itemize} \\ \hline\T
\textbf{Blah} & Blah\\
& \textit{Blah} \\
& \textit{Blah} \\
& \begin{itemize}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\textendash}
\vspace{-1em}
\itemsep-1ex
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\end{itemize} \\ \cline{2-2}\T
& Blah\\
& \textit{Blah} \\
& \begin{itemize}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\textendash}
\vspace{-1em}
\itemsep-1ex
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\item Blah
\end{itemize} \\ \cline{2-2}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The list is inside a row and it will never break. Don't use `longtable` but only a `list`.

Comment: hi @HarishKumar thanks for the answer. Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: whenever you have a table with a thin first column with one word entries and a wide second column taking up the rest of the page it is an indication that it should not be a table at all but a list. If the outer list was set as a list the inner lists would break over a page with no problem.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, can I do that and preserve the formatting?

Comment: Probably:-) several examples on this site, eg http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87592/best-practices-longtable/87601#87601

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Will you construct an answer or should the OP do that?

Comment: @masu close as dup, I guess