# how to make longtable continue a long row to next page?

Tags: longtable

I have a long table of 4 rows. I'd like help to make the table look better.

(based on comments, this is not possible to do using `longtable`. Is there a different
table environment or package I can use to do this? as long as the data remains all in a table looking environment of some sort, I am ok with it).

The second row is small, and the third row is large. Latex leaves lots of empty space after the second row before starting the third row

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The third row is large, and longtable does not break this row but overflows to the bottom of the page. How to correct this output?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{1.5in}|p{4.5in}|}\hline

Row 1&1, 286, 484, 507, 790, 920 \\\hline
Row 2&16, 22, 80, 81, 83, 86, 127, 188, 266, 365, 385, 394, 400, 402, 404, 413, 414, 416, 428, 429, 430, 451, 465, 467, 468, 479, 487, 489, 494, 504, 509, 513, 515, 523, 524, 527, 528, 530, 533, 534, 535, 538, 541, 542, 544, 546, 550, 555, 561, 566, 567, 570, 620, 638, 639, 640, 672, 701, 703, 706, 714, 730, 735, 743, 745, 746, 747, 752, 759, 769, 776, 782, 783, 784, 785, 786, 807, 854, 855, 862, 889, 892, 909, 913, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 922, 923, 925, 926, 929, 932, 942, 953, 961, 996, 1000 \\\hline
Row 3&2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 51, 52, 53, 54, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 75, 76, 77, 78, 84, 85, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 204, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 235, 236, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 251, 252, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 267, 268, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 366, 369, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 384, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 396, 397, 398, 399, 401, 403, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 415, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 462, 463, 464, 466, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 481, 483, 486, 488, 490, 491, 492, 493, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 505, 508, 511, 512, 514, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 525, 526, 529, 532, 536, 539, 540, 545, 547, 548, 549, 551, 552, 553, 554, 556, 557, 558, 559, 560, 562, 563, 564, 565, 568, 569, 571, 573, 574, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 600, 601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 607, 608, 609, 610, 611, 612, 613, 614, 615, 616, 617, 618, 619, 621, 622, 623, 624, 625, 626, 627, 628, 629, 630, 631, 632, 633, 634, 635, 636, 637, 641, 642, 643, 644, 645, 646, 647, 648, 649, 650, 651, 652, 653, 654, 655, 656, 657, 658, 659, 660, 661, 662, 663, 664, 665, 666, 667, 668, 669, 670, 671, 673, 674, 675, 676, 677, 678, 679, 680, 681, 682, 683, 684, 685, 686, 687, 688, 689, 690, 691, 692, 693, 694, 695, 696, 697, 698, 699, 700, 702, 704, 705, 707, 708, 709, 710, 711, 712, 713, 715, 716, 717, 718, 719, 720, 721, 722, 723, 724, 725, 726, 727, 728, 729, 731, 732, 734, 736, 737, 738, 739, 740, 741, 742, 744, 748, 749, 750, 751, 753, 754, 755, 756, 757, 758, 760, 761, 762, 763, 764, 765, 766, 767, 768, 770, 771, 772, 773, 774, 775, 777, 778, 779, 780, 781, 787, 791, 792, 793, 794, 795, 796, 797, 798, 799, 800, 801, 802, 803, 804, 805, 806, 808, 809, 810, 811, 812, 813, 814, 815, 816, 817, 818, 819, 820, 821, 822, 823, 824, 825, 826, 827, 828, 829, 830, 831, 832, 833, 834, 836, 838, 839, 840, 841, 842, 843, 844, 845, 846, 847, 848, 849, 850, 851, 852, 853, 856, 857, 858, 859, 860, 861, 863, 864, 865, 866, 867, 868, 869, 870, 871, 872, 873, 874, 875, 876, 877, 878, 879, 880, 881, 882, 883, 884, 886, 887, 888, 890, 891, 893, 895, 896, 897, 898, 899, 900, 901, 902, 903, 904, 905, 906, 907, 908, 910, 911, 912, 914, 921, 924, 927, 928, 930, 931, 933, 934, 935, 936, 937, 938, 939, 940, 941, 943, 944, 945, 946, 947, 948, 949, 950, 951, 952, 954, 955, 956, 957, 958, 959, 960, 962, 963, 964, 965, 966, 967, 968, 969, 970, 971, 972, 973, 974, 975, 976, 977, 978, 979, 980, 981, 982, 983, 984, 985, 986, 987, 988, 989, 990, 991, 992, 993, 994, 995, 997, 998, 999 \\\hline
Row 4&38, 47, 48, 49, 50, 55, 56, 74, 79, 82, 87, 110, 121, 202, 203, 205, 206, 219, 234, 237, 250, 253, 265, 269, 331, 340, 367, 368, 370, 383, 395, 452, 460, 461, 480, 482, 485, 503, 506, 510, 531, 537, 543, 572, 575, 576, 733, 788, 789, 835, 837, 885, 894\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Using texlive 2014

Comment: According to the `longtable` document,  "TEX will never break a page within such a row". That is, it will never break a row within a "p column". You'll have to manually break the row or use another table environment (I don't have any suggestions I'm afraid).

Comment: @Andrew thanks. I'll update my question to ask for alternative solution to using long table in this case.

Comment: You can use a list instead. Those vertical lines aren't good looking anyway!

Comment: 99999 times out of 10 a 2 column table with large data in the second column is best set as a list (there are several duplicate questions saying this, I'll find some)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135333/parameter-description-with-long-descriptions-and-long-lists-possibility-of-pa   or  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87592/best-practices-longtable/87601#87601

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `longtable` environment is not capable of breaking a table inside a cell, and I doubt it will ever be. The true problem is that your table is semantically not a table, it is a list of lists. Therefore I would use one of the list environments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}

\item[Case 1.]
1, 286, 484, 507, 790, 920.

\item[Case 2.]
16, 22, 80, 81, 83, 86, 127, 188, 266, 365, 385, 394, 400, 402, 404, 413, 414, 416, 428, 429, 430, 451, 465, 467, 468, 479, 487, 489, 494, 504, 509, 513, 515, 523, 524, 527, 528, 530, 533, 534, 535, 538, 541, 542, 544, 546, 550, 555, 561, 566, 567, 570, 620, 638, 639, 640, 672, 701, 703, 706, 714, 730, 735, 743, 745, 746, 747, 752, 759, 769, 776, 782, 783, 784, 785, 786, 807, 854, 855, 862, 889, 892, 909, 913, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 922, 923, 925, 926, 929, 932, 942, 953, 961, 996, 1000.

\item[Case 3.]
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 51, 52, 53, 54, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 75, 76, 77, 78, 84, 85, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 204, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 235, 236, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 251, 252, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 267, 268, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 366, 369, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 384, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 396, 397, 398, 399, 401, 403, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 415, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 462, 463, 464, 466, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 481, 483, 486, 488, 490, 491, 492, 493, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 505, 508, 511, 512, 514, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 525, 526, 529, 532, 536, 539, 540, 545, 547, 548, 549, 551, 552, 553, 554, 556, 557, 558, 559, 560, 562, 563, 564, 565, 568, 569, 571, 573, 574, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 600, 601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 607, 608, 609, 610, 611, 612, 613, 614, 615, 616, 617, 618, 619, 621, 622, 623, 624, 625, 626, 627, 628, 629, 630, 631, 632, 633, 634, 635, 636, 637, 641, 642, 643, 644, 645, 646, 647, 648, 649, 650, 651, 652, 653, 654, 655, 656, 657, 658, 659, 660, 661, 662, 663, 664, 665, 666, 667, 668, 669, 670, 671, 673, 674, 675, 676, 677, 678, 679, 680, 681, 682, 683, 684, 685, 686, 687, 688, 689, 690, 691, 692, 693, 694, 695, 696, 697, 698, 699, 700, 702, 704, 705, 707, 708, 709, 710, 711, 712, 713, 715, 716, 717, 718, 719, 720, 721, 722, 723, 724, 725, 726, 727, 728, 729, 731, 732, 734, 736, 737, 738, 739, 740, 741, 742, 744, 748, 749, 750, 751, 753, 754, 755, 756, 757, 758, 760, 761, 762, 763, 764, 765, 766, 767, 768, 770, 771, 772, 773, 774, 775, 777, 778, 779, 780, 781, 787, 791, 792, 793, 794, 795, 796, 797, 798, 799, 800, 801, 802, 803, 804, 805, 806, 808, 809, 810, 811, 812, 813, 814, 815, 816, 817, 818, 819, 820, 821, 822, 823, 824, 825, 826, 827, 828, 829, 830, 831, 832, 833, 834, 836, 838, 839, 840, 841, 842, 843, 844, 845, 846, 847, 848, 849, 850, 851, 852, 853, 856, 857, 858, 859, 860, 861, 863, 864, 865, 866, 867, 868, 869, 870, 871, 872, 873, 874, 875, 876, 877, 878, 879, 880, 881, 882, 883, 884, 886, 887, 888, 890, 891, 893, 895, 896, 897, 898, 899, 900, 901, 902, 903, 904, 905, 906, 907, 908, 910, 911, 912, 914, 921, 924, 927, 928, 930, 931, 933, 934, 935, 936, 937, 938, 939, 940, 941, 943, 944, 945, 946, 947, 948, 949, 950, 951, 952, 954, 955, 956, 957, 958, 959, 960, 962, 963, 964, 965, 966, 967, 968, 969, 970, 971, 972, 973, 974, 975, 976, 977, 978, 979, 980, 981, 982, 983, 984, 985, 986, 987, 988, 989, 990, 991, 992, 993, 994, 995, 997, 998, 999.

\item[Case 4.]
38, 47, 48, 49, 50, 55, 56, 74, 79, 82, 87, 110, 121, 202, 203, 205, 206, 219, 234, 237, 250, 253, 265, 269, 331, 340, 367, 368, 370, 383, 395, 452, 460, 461, 480, 482, 485, 503, 506, 510, 531, 537, 543, 572, 575, 576, 733, 788, 789, 835, 837, 885, 894.

\end{description}

\end{document}
```