# Long table starts in previous blank page

Tags: longtable, blank-page

I am writing a longtable that spread across 2 pages. But LaTeX always adds starts the table in a new page rather than the previous blank page.

Now I want my longtable starts in the previous blank page (like the pictuer bellow), how can I do that? Thank you.

[image: The final result I want.]

Here is my *.tex：

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{10cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{First} & \textbf{Second entry}  \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
 1   &   \lipsum[1]  \\ \hline
 2   &   \lipsum[2]  \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Never put longtable in a `center` environment, it just adds spurious space (it has no effect on its horizontal alignment) but here you have a long lipsum entry in the first row of the table so it does not fit in the previous page. (longtable only breaks between rows, not in the middle of a cell)

Comment: It would be better to set this as a _list_ rather than a table, then page breaking would naturally be allowed in the middle of long items.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87592/best-practices-longtable which has some suggestions eg on using a list but this is a duplicate of: